# merge tsv files in one csv by extracting particular columns and naming the column as file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have multiple tsv files in folder. From each file I have to extract 1st column which is the abundance and 5th column which is ID, there are no headers for columns. I have to merge these columns from each file in one file and give their headers as there file name. Also I have to compare check if all the ID'a are present, if not then value should be zero.

One of the sample files `File_Name1` looks like:

```
0.11    31  31  U   0   unclassified
99.89   29001   0   -   1         root
99.89   29001   0   -   131567    cellular organisms
99.89   29001   64  D   2         Bacteria
59.94   17401   270 -   1783272   Terrabacteria group
53.47   15522   8   P   1239      Firmicutes
52.10   15127   998 C   186801    Clostridia
37.83   10982   494 O   186802    Clostridiales
20.61   5983    89  F   186803    Lachnospiraceae
16.95   4922    8   G   1506553   Lachnoclostridium
14.53   4219    0   S   84030     [Clostridium] saccharolyticum
```

Similarly I have multiple files. The file I want is like :

```
ID           File_Name1       File_Name2
186802       16.95            37.88
1506553      20.61            0
84030        14.53            0.05
```

I have tried something like this:

```
import glob
import csv
directory = "C:\kraken\kraken_13266"
txt_files = glob.glob(directory+"\*.kraken")

for txt_file in txt_files:
    with open(txt_file, "rt") as input_file, open('output.csv', "wt") as 
    out_file:
     in_txt = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\t')
     for line in in_txt:
         firstcolumns = line[:1]
         lastcolumns = line[-2].strip().split(",")
         allcolumns = firstcolumns + lastcolumns
```

I'm stuck at this point. How should I proceed further.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x?

Comment: Is `File Name : File_Name1` the first line in each TSV file? Or is the filename itself `File_Name1.kraken` ?

Comment: Hi, martin. I'm using python 3.x and the file name is "File_Name1". There are no headers in the tsv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do what you are trying to do:

```
from collections import defaultdict    
import glob
import csv

ids = defaultdict(dict)        # e.g. {'186802' : {'FileName1' : '16.95', 'FileName2' : '37.88'}}
kraken_files = glob.glob('*.kraken')

for kraken_filename in kraken_files:
    with open(kraken_filename, 'r', newline='') as f_input:
        csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
        file_name = os.path.splitext(kraken_filename)[0]

        for row in csv_input:
            ids[int(row[4])].update({file_name : float(row[0])})

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    fieldnames = ['ID'] + [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in kraken_files]
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames, restval=0)
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for id in sorted(ids.keys()):
        id_values = ids[id]
        id_values['ID'] = id
        csv_output.writerow(id_values)
```

You will need to read all of the files in before you are able to write an output file. A dictionary is used to store all the IDs. For each one a dictionary is used to hold each file that contains a matching ID.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin. I worked wonders and also helped to understand the logic that needed to be applied to such problems. :)